# Getting "Scheme missing" error with wget

Tags: bash, wget

I wrote a little script that grabs a random wallpaper from the [Desktoppr](https://www.desktoppr.co/) API and changes my desktop wallpaper to it:

```
#!/bin/bash
url=$(curl 'https://api.desktoppr.co/1/wallpapers?page='$(shuf -i 1-1000 -n 1) | jq ".response[].image.url" | sed $(shuf -i 1-20 -n 1)'!d') &&
wget "$url"
```

When I run the script, the final `wget` command fails with the error:

```
"http://a.desktopprassets.com/wallpapers/...jpg": Scheme missing.
```

When I put the URL directly into the wget command, like so:

```
wget "http://a.desktopprassets.com/wallpapers/...jpg"
```

... the command executes correctly and downloads the image, meaning that the error occurs because of some problem in the variable.

I think this might have something to do with the [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) library that I am using to parse the JSON response from the Desktoprr API.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to remove the double quotes surrounding the URL, for example by using the `-r` option to `jq`:

```
url=$(curl 'https://api.desktoppr.co/1/wallpapers?page='$(shuf -i 1-1000 -n 1) | jq -r ".response[].image.url" | sed $(shuf -i 1-20 -n 1)'!d')
```

Currently the command actually results in

```
wget "\"http://a.desktopprassets.com/wallpapers/...jpg\""
```

Comment: Bravo. This problem had me slamming the keyboard. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem like this.

### This return the Scheme Missing Error:

```sh
resources=$(cat complete_list_of_urls.txt)
for resource in ${resources[@]};
do
    wget --no-check-certificate https://cyberican.com/images/images/$resource
done
```

### By removing the (") quotation marks, I could extract the data.

```sh
resources=$(cat complete_list_of_urls.txt | tr -d '\"')
for resource in ${resources[@]};
do
    wget --no-check-certificate https://cyberican.com/images/images/$resource
done
```

I hope this help anyone having the same problem :-)